# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException in REST with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, wildfly-8

I am trying to create REST service using Spring.When I try to access that service it returns proper data but shows -

```
Exception handling request to /RESTServ/user/2: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:177) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.get(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:160) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.containsKey(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:142) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.addContentDispositionHeader(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:349) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:221) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I have checked for the data it returns and it is not null by applying breakpoints but still it shows above exception.

**EDITED:**

Code is:
**User.java**
    package com.rest.service;

```
public class User {

    private int userid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userid=" + userid + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

**SpringServiceController.java**

```
package com.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.rest.dao.UserService;
import com.rest.service.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/")
public class SpringServiceController {

    UserService userService = new UserService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I am getting data from database using UserService.java
**DBUtility** is class to connect to JDBC

```
 package com.rest.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.rest.service.User;
import com.rest.utility.DBUtility;

public class UserService {

    private Connection connection;

    public UserService() {
        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement
                    .executeQuery("select * from tblUser");
            while (rs.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return users;
    }

    public User getUserById(int userId) {
        User user = new User();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from tblUser where userid=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));

                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RESTServ</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

And this is my rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rest.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

PS: One more thing when I delete annotation-driven tag from spring xml file then it works for simple datatype. But it doesn't work where json conversion is required.I am using WildFly - 8.1

Comment: any code or your servlet or code?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "O/P"?

Comment: Added code..please let me know if anything else is required to track this issue.

Comment: are you using `maven`? if so can u post the `pom.xml` and which server your are deploying?

Comment: I faced the same error, but in my case the error was because, I hadn't defined the getters, so it couldn't deserialize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is an issue with WildFly - 8.1 you have to use WildFly - 8.2 or use Jboss 7.

Comment: You saved my time, Thanks :)

Comment: even I am using Jboss EAP 7.1.4 GA version. I am still having problem when reading saml data from the url. @Nikhi do you have any idea?

Exception is:
 url, Please contact idp system administrator
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-48) [] UT005023: Exception handling request to /ssoadmin/metadata/search: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at

Answer (score 3):

We faced this issue while trial to migrate spring-boot-1.2.2-Final on wildfly 8.1.0-Final to spring-boot-1.3.2-Final on wildfly 8.1.0-Final.
This error does not occur on wildfly 8.2.1-Final, so if you have option tp udate your wildfly version, you should do that.

But if you still have to use wildfly-8.1.0-Final, then you could **patch** it.

1) get https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/archive/1.0.15.Final.zip

2) edit io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl located in module servlet

```
@Override
public String getHeaders(final String name) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(exchange.getResponseHeaders().get(name));
}
```

to

```
@Override
public Collection<String> getHeaders(final String name) {
    final HeaderValues headerValues = exchange.getResponseHeaders().get(name);
    if (headerValues != null) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(headerValues);
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Add the `HeaderValues` import:

```
import io.undertow.util.HeaderValues;
```

package undertow-servlet with maven and then overwrite

**{wildfly-root-directory}/modules/system/layers/base/io/undertow/servlet/main/undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar**

with the file

**{undertow-root-directory}/servlet/target/undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar**

This will solve this error.

Comment: I'm not able to upgrade my project to > 8.2.*, and your solution really saved me! Thank you. Note: You actually want to replace the original ```public Collection<String> getHeaders(final String name) ``` method, not the ```public String getHeader(final String name)``` method

Answer (score 1):

If your are using `maven`, add `JSON Databinding` dependencies specified below in your `pom.xml` and annotate the `User` class  with `@JsonRootName(value = "user")`,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven.I am using eclipse to build the project and wildfly 8.1 as server

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to those who aren't able to upgrade past Wildfly 8.1.0 in their project to address this problem. Ingvar's answer above of patching the code helped me out a lot, and here is a script that will perform the patch in one command for you (keeping a backup of your previous copy):

https://github.com/ldojo/wf-8.1.0-undertow-1.0.15-patch