# Something went wrong when using spring boot with jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly-8

When I used spring-boot with the wildfly, something went wrong. 
The following is my application and conf.

1. pom.xml:

   ```
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. Main code: Application.java (return JSON data)

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/")
   public Map<String, String> hello() {
       Map<String, String> retMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
       retMap.put("success", "true");
       return retMap;
   }
   ```
3. Wildfly version:

   WildFly 8.1.0.Final
4. Exception:

   ```
   2017-02-27 11:53:33,533 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [null]: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:303) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
       at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.get(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:161) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.containsKey(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:143) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.addContentDispositionHeader(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:352) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:230) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
   ```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Same as this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354481/org-springframework-web-util-nestedservletexception-request-processing-failed/34356729

Comment: Try setting the servlet-api dependency to `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: tks Karthik Prasad.

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3474